# View in getChildView method

Tags: android, view

I have a simple `View` in my layout for my child group of the expandable `listview`. And I want to change the background color of that View. This is how I do it:

```
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    ...
    View colorView = (View) view.findViewById(R.id.color_view);
    colorView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.my_color);
    ...
    return view;
}
```

Whatever I do, I can't get it to change the color. When I try to change the background of a `TextView` in that same ChildGroup it works, how come? If you need more code let me know.

Comment: You getting any error ? or exception ?

Comment: No errors nor exception. :/

Comment: show us your full code...

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
colorView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.my_color));
```

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. I want to use my own colors.

Comment: Edited the answer see it please

Answer (score 0):

ues this

```
colorView.setBackgroundResource(getResources().getColor(R.color.my_color));
```

instead of

```
colorView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.my_color);
```

Comment: With this i got an Resources$NotFoundException for the color res. But I dont get it, i have the color. I successfully changed the color of a textview background.